# Version control for BusinessObjects

Tags: version-control, business-objects

How would go about implementing version control for BusinessObjects (as in the BI solution)? Ideally we would like to have some sort of way of getting artifacts into our Subversion repository. (I don't know much about BusinessObjects to be honest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main products in the market are:

- [Version Manager (VM)](http://www.ebiexperts.com/cms/products/version-manager.html) by [ebiexperts](http://www.ebiexperts.com/):

  > Version Manager® (VM) is a
  >   comprehensive, yet simple-to-use,
  >   version control tool for SAP
  >   BusinessObjects. Multiple versions of
  >   Universes and Reports can be managed,
  >   compared, and securley controlled,
  >   providing complete integrity of your
  >   SAP BusinessObjects environment.
  >
  > Version Manager is designed for SAP
  >   BusinessObjects, Web Intelligence, and
  >   Crystal, but open to use for other
  >   files also. All information is stored
  >   in the Version manager Repository, and
  >   there is no impact or overhead to any
  >   part of your SAP BusinessObjects
  >   environment.
- [EQM](http://www.noadbi.com/en/noad-eqm) by [NOAD](http://www.noadbi.com/): which is also available in a [QuickStart edition](http://www.noadbi.com/en/QuickStart).

Answer (score 2):

BusinessObjects Life Cycle Manager, is a proprietary tool from SAP BusinessObjects. It has inbuilt support for versioning through Subversion.

This tool is also the recommended tool for promotions and versioning between environments.